# Wrong number of type arguments when returning a HashMap from a function

Tags: function, hashmap, rust, return-type

I've built a basic function which loads application settings from a configuration file. These settings are parsed and inserted into a `HashMap` so I can reference them later on. I cannot seem to find a correct way to return my `HashMap` and the data it contains:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn load_config_files(settings: &str) -> HashMap {
    println!("Loading configuration file...");

    let mut settings_data = HashMap::new();

    //function returns a vector with the application settings...
    let handle = File::open(settings).unwrap();

    for line in BufReader::new(handle).lines() {
        let mut line_data = &line.unwrap();

        //get the first charater, if its a # then the line is ignored... e.g. comments
        let first_character = &line_data[0..1];
        if first_character != "#" {
            //sort into a vector
            let mut settings_info_split = line_data.split("=");
            let settings_info = settings_info_split.collect::<Vec<&str>>();

            //need to add the values to the "settings_vector"
            settings_data.insert(settings_info[0], settings_info[1]);
        }
    }

    return settings_data;
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:5:41
  |
5 | fn load_config_files(settings: &str) -> HashMap {
  |                                         ^^^^^^^ expected at least 2 type arguments
```

I've tried including the parameters it's after, but I cannot find the right ones... E.g. it did not like `&str`, it did not like `String`.

Comment: `fn load_config_files(settings: &str) -> HashMap<String, String>` and `settings_data.insert(settings_info[0].to_owned(), settings_info[1].to_owned());`

Comment: In the future, please *include* the error message you get and describe what you mean by "it did not like". That's mostly useless for anyone else.